# Using Raspberry Pi to control light dimmer switch

Tags: hardware, power, relay, voltage

In my house I have my lights hooked up to an ELKO 400GLI. I've not found good spec sheets for it online, but what it seems to do is control the brightness of the lights using a copper coil.

What I want to do is hook up the Raspberry pi to this dimmer switch, so that I can control the dimness (and if possible power state), from both the raspberry pi and the dimmer switch itself. I've honestly no idea how to approach this in a safe and reasonable way. I would prefer having to use as little peripherals and going bare metal as possible, but I have a feeling that some sort of relay is unavoidable.

Additionally I would like to be able to control the Pi from my phone using for example Wi-Fi and hooking it up to Apple Homekit, but these I can reasonably figure out on my own.

Could anyone point me in the right direction to get this project started?

P.S
I have multiple Raspberry Pi 1 Model B boards to use for this project.

[Here are some pictures of the ELKO 400GLI to help.](https://imgur.com/a/j9fz2YL)

Comment: use a servo motor to operate the ELKO 400GLI ... I'm assuming that a ELKO 400GLI is a dimmer ... you did not actually say what it is ...connecting to the dimmer electrically is not safe

Comment: I added some pictures of the ELKO to help. I was considering a servo, but to turn on and off the light you press down on the switch, and I couldn't come up with a way to achieve that cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have detailed data, then connecting the Pi to this dimmer would be very risky; on simple dimmers, the control knob adjusts the trigger angle of a triac, using a potentiometer that is directly connected to the mains. So you'd need some form of galvanic isolation when emulating the potentiometer, but this isn't easy, and you'd need to consider the safety issues really carefully.